# css3 page media not working in any browser

Tags: html, css, printing-web-page, css-paged-media, css-gcpm

Hello I have used [CSS3 page media module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/) to print html content to PDF directly from browser but I am not getting any browser to work it on. My working is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
@media print {

body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        font: 12pt "sans-serif";
        position: relative;
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }


        @page {
            size: letter;
            margin: 20mm 25mm;
        }
        @page {
            @top-center {
                content: element(pageHeader);
            }
        }

        @page  {
            @bottom-center {
                content: element(pageFooter);
            }
        }
        #pageHeader {
          position: running(pageHeader);
        }
        #pageFooter{
          position: running(pageFooter);
        }

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pageHeader">
    <p>This is the Header shown on first page.</p>
</div>
<div id="pageFooter">
    <p>This is the footer shown on last page.</p>
</div>
<section class="page"> 

<h1>Introduction</h1>
<p>The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:</p>

<p>
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:

</p>
<p>The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:
The margins can be set as displayed in the examples above, or can be set for each side individually, as shown in the code snippet below, where the top and bottom margins are set to 2cm, and the left and right margins are set to 3cm:</p>


 </section>


 </body>
</html>
```

It does not work in any browser for me. I have tested it in latest Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari. It should show the header and footer on every page. The header is intended to be shown on top of every page and footer at the bottom of every page. Can any one have working example of CSS3 page media module elements that actually works. Also I am not looking for position absolute or fixed solution of header and footer. I have tried it and it does not work except for single page. I have shorten my text content for this question but it can be copy and past to produce multiple page document to see multiple pages without header and footer. The header and footer div stays at top.

Comment: I want this. :] I'm looking for this feature support.

Answer (score 3):

It's not currently supported in any of the end-user browsers, but it is supported in PrinceXML, a dedicated engine for generating PDFs. See [the CSS3 support for Margin boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)#Grammar_and_rules).

PrinceXML is a commercial product, but I use it for creating the print version of novels from a HTML source. It supports a comprehensive list of printing-related features. (I am not affiliated with them in any way.)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because that specification is from a W3C working draft rather than an actual implementation, so there are no browsers yet that implement this proposed spec? In fact, it isn't even proposed quite yet - it is being discussed as a "working draft", meaning it is open for discussion and hasn't even made it into an "editor's draft". From there it could still be a while before you see it available in a browser. That working draft has a relatively recent date on it as well - May 13, 2014 - so beware of implementing any of that proposal for a while.  That said, this does look like a handy addition.

For now, what about using the CSS pseudo element 'before', or 'after' along with a tag in that header position?

Here is a good description of the differences between working draft and editors draft:
[What is the difference between a W3C Working Draft and an Editor's Draft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692762/what-is-the-difference-between-a-w3c-working-draft-and-an-editors-draft)

Comment: You've misunderstood the W3C development process and completely misunderstood [What is the difference between a W3C Working Draft and an Editor's Draft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692762/what-is-the-difference-between-a-w3c-working-draft-and-an-editors-draft)   An editor's draft is not something that happens to a working draft once it starts to stabilise.  The editor's draft is the live development copy of the document, and working drafts are snapshots made from it from time to time.  It's impossible for there to be a working draft without an editor's draft, and there isn't here.